Windows resource file (.rc) : RTEXT vs. LTEXT with WS_EX_RIGHT style
While doing localisation of dialogs in an .rc file I came upon following difference in the definition of a right aligned static control:

in the original resource file a static control in a DIALOGEX is defined like this: LTEXT "some text",IDC_STATIC,14,24,17,8,0,WS_EX_RIGHT
in the translated resource file the same static control is defined like this:RTEXT "some translated text",IDC_STATIC,14,24,17,8,0

With both resource files the text is displayed right aligned as expected.
Is there a difference between both ways? Or is LTEXT with WS_EX_RIGHT just another way than RTEXT for displaying right aligned text?
I use the current version of Visual Studio 2022.
Actually there seems to be some redundancy. In the resource editor the Align Text property controls whether you get RTEXT, CTEXT or LTEXT and the Right Align Text property controls the presence of the WS_EX_RIGHT style.


If you define a static text item as LTEXT, and then give it the WS_EX_RIGHT style, then it will be right aligned, as explained at Extended Window Styles.

Only use WS_EX_RIGHT for windows that display text in a language with right-to-left reading order (like Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi, etc).  L/RTEXT merely affects text alignment, not reading order.  It might seem that it aligns Western text, but quirks related to punctuation will result.

According to LTEXT control, CTEXT control and RTEXT control, they have SS_LEFT, SS_CENTER and SS_RIGHT respectively.
And according to WS_EX_RIGHT,



Constant/value
Description




WS_EX_RIGHT 0x00001000L
The window has generic "right-aligned" properties. This depends on the window class. This style has an effect only if the shell language is Hebrew, Arabic, or another language that supports reading-order alignment; otherwise, the style is ignored. Using the WS_EX_RIGHT style for static or edit controls has the same effect as using the SS_RIGHT or ES_RIGHT style, respectively. Using this style with button controls has the same effect as using BS_RIGHT and BS_RIGHTBUTTON styles.



